# Infinite Scroller duplicating list results [ReactJS]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so I'm working on a pokedex project that is linked to the PokeAPI. I have the main page that loads up the list ans the code for PokemonList.js is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PokemonCard from "./PokemonCard";
import axios from "axios";
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroller";

export default class PokemonList extends Component {
  state = {
    url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=20&offset=0.",
    pokemon: null,
    itemsCountPerPage: 20,
    activePage: 1,
    count: 365,
    previous: null
  };

  loadPokemon = () => {
    axios
      .get(this.state.url)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState(prevState => {
          return {
            pokemon: [...prevState.pokemon, ...res.data.results],
            url: res.data.next
          };
        });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const res = await axios.get(this.state.url);
    this.setState({ pokemon: res.data["results"] });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.pokemon);
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.state.pokemon ? (
          <div className="row">
            <InfiniteScroll
              pageStart={1}
              loadMore={this.loadPokemon}
              hasMore={true}
              loader={
                <div className="loader" key={0}>
                  Loading ...
                </div>
              }
            >
              {this.state.pokemon.map((pokemon, i) => (
                <PokemonCard
                  key={pokemon.name + i}
                  name={pokemon.name}
                  url={pokemon.url}
                />
              ))}
            </InfiniteScroll>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <h1>Loading Pokemon</h1>
        )}
      </React.Fragment>

      /*<React.Fragment>
        {this.state.pokemon ? (
          <div className="row">
            {this.state.pokemon.map(pokemon => (
              <PokemonCard
                key={pokemon.name}
                name={pokemon.name}
                url={pokemon.url}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        ) : (
          <h1>Loading Pokemon</h1>
        )}
      </React.Fragment>*/
    );
  }
}
```

For some reason, the first 20 PokemonCards are loaded in from the API, but once I reach the 20th one, the infinite scroller loads up the first 20 again before eventually loading the next 20-40, then 40-60. It is only the first set amount that is duplicated.

This is a screenshot of the console being returned

[image]

As you can see, Bulbasaur is repeated after the 20th data in the list.

Comment: https://github.com/CassetteRocks/react-infinite-scroller/issues/164
check this may help you

Comment: @KishanJaiswal That didn't seem to fix the issue for some reason

Comment: console your api response ,just see its giving next 20 or not

Comment: @KishanJaiswal So it loads up the initial 20, when i reach the bottom, it preloads the first 20 again, then it loads 20-40, and then 40-60, so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not called the `loadPokemon` function inside your `componentDidMount()`. Remove it and it should work as expected!

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PokemonCard from "./PokemonCard";
import axios from "axios";
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroller";

export default class PokemonList extends Component {
  state = {
    url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=20&offset=0.",
    pokemon: [],
    itemsCountPerPage: 20,
    activePage: 1,
    count: 365,
    previous: null
  };

  loadPokemon = () => {
    axios
      .get(this.state.url)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState(prevState => {
          return {
            pokemon: [...prevState.pokemon, ...res.data.results],
            url: res.data.next
          };
        });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.pokemon);
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.state.pokemon ? (
          <div className="row">
            <InfiniteScroll
              pageStart={1}
              loadMore={this.loadPokemon}
              hasMore={true}
              loader={
                <div className="loader" key={0}>
                  Loading ...
                </div>
              }
            >
              {this.state.pokemon.map((pokemon, i) => (
                <PokemonCard
                  key={pokemon.name + i}
                  name={pokemon.name}
                  url={pokemon.url}
                />
              ))}
            </InfiniteScroll>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <h1>Loading Pokemon</h1>
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing my state from

```
pokemon: null,
```

to

```
pokemon: [],
```

And I added

```
const pokemon = prevState.pokemon;
```

to my loadPokemon Function

Comment: This is not an efficient solution. You should only removed your `componentDidMount` and everything will work out ;)

Comment: @JulienRioux This solution is more-or-less the last solution you suggested, so i'll mark yours as the right answer. I didn't or wouldn't need to remove componentDidMount

Answer (score 0):

In your componentDidMount function, you need to set your this.state.url, just like you do each time loadPokemon is called. You are calling the base url twice for the first page currently, once in componentDidMount and again in loadPokemon.